# Error in ggplot2 density plot: "Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette."

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having installed tidyverse, I can't get the following to work....

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species) + geom_density(alpha = .3)
```

The error reads: "Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette."

Any ideas?

Comment: i suppose, you have not have not provide the whole your code? am i right?

Comment: it has nothing to do with your update of packages. if you are suspect of it, restart your RStudio. But, i think, the problem comes from your code which you did not share it with us.

Comment: Hi @Salman restarting it seems to have cleared the problem, so thank you for the tip :) FYI - the only code that preceded the line in my original question was: `library(tidyverse)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot get this error from your code. Your code works well, you just missed a close parentheses `)`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
         geom_density(alpha = .3)
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Yeah my bad, missed the extra ) but even then it still fails for me. Can't help thinking this is linked to me updating my packages yesterday in R Studio, and since then I've had no end of problems (not finding "stringi" package for example).

Answer (score 11):

Just for the record and for future readers, I had this error related with the specific column (`iris$Species` in this example) containing only NAs.

This happened because some libraries did not work properly after sourcing my code, and therefore some tables didn't have the proper format.

Answer (score 1):

just for the record and for future readers, sometimes the sourcing of the code does not work

```
source("code_that_generates_data_for_ggplot.R")
```

and the data that is the GGPLOT input have one or more missing variables. This happens 
since some of the data is encoded in UTF-8.

A possible solution to this is using

```
source("code_that_generates_data_for_ggplot.R", encoding="UTF-8")
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I was calling a column witch a forgot to fill.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes if the column given as 'fill' contain all NAs.

So effectively it does not request for any color.

That would explain the error

> "Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette."

I tried the below code, with 'condition' containing only NAs, and obtained the same error

```
  ggplot(grouped_info) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = label, y = n, fill = condition), stat = "identity")
```