# R error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create demographic distribution maps, and I keep getting this error: `Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.` This issue has been raised many times on SO, and the common theme seems to be that there are NAs in whatever is being supplied to the fill/color argument (e.g., see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182976/error-in-ggplot2-density-plot-error-must-request-at-least-one-colour-from-a-h), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555228/ggplot-error-must-request-at-least-one-colour-from-a-hue-palette), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649772/what-is-causing-must-request-at-least-one-colour-from-a-hue-palette-error-in-m)). I have removed NAs and still get the error:

```
> sum(is.na(test_data$analysis_group))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(test_data$census_block_id))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(test_data$race))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(test_data$dem_count))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(test_data$dem_perc))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(test_data$dist_miles))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(test_data$geog))
[1] 0
```

I also tried setting the `na.value` parameter as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569175/need-to-create-ggplot-heatmap-with-na-only-data-but-get-error-must-request-at), but I still get the error.

Here is a glimpse of the data:

```
> test_data %>% glimpse() 
Rows: 529,980 
Columns: 7 
$ analysis_group  <fct> DMV and Hospital, DMV and Hospital, DMV and Hospital, DMV and Hospit… 
$ census_block_id <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,… 
$ race            <fct> hisp_lat_white, total_non_white, v3_American_Indian_and_Alaska_Nativ… 
$ dem_count       <int> 6, 57, 2, 0, 47, 0, 2, 0, 57, 0, 12, 62, 0, 4, 32, 0, 9, 5, 72, 10, … 
$ dem_perc <dbl> 0.1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.9, 0.0,
    0.1… 
$ dist_miles      <dbl> 0.2262349, 0.2262349, 0.2262349, 0.2262349, 0.2262349, 0.2262349, 0.… 
$ geog            <POLYGON [°]> POLYGON ((-75.14961 40.0082..., POLYGON ((-75.14961 40.0082.…
```

The above data (test_data) are being fed into this ggplot call:

```
test_data %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = dem_perc, color = NA)
```

Interestingly, another dataset that is formatted the same, but with different variables, maps just fine:

```
Rows: 52,998
Columns: 15
$ comparison                     <fct> DMV to both, DMV to both, DMV to both, DMV to both, D…
$ census_block_id                <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16…
$ dist_change                    <dbl> -3.69399923, -4.03896796, -2.71867327, -0.39305133, -…
$ dist_initial                   <dbl> 3.920234, 6.234878, 3.582916, 1.474123, 2.520320, 1.8…
$ dist_final                     <dbl> 0.2262349, 2.1959098, 0.8642427, 1.0810720, 2.0617893…
$ dist_percchange                <dbl> -94.229046, -64.780227, -75.878790, -26.663395, -18.1…
$ race                           <chr> "v3_TOTAL", "v3_TOTAL", "v3_TOTAL", "v3_TOTAL", "v3_T…
$ dem_count                      <int> 57, 72, 55, 144, 78, 0, 117, 23, 5, 35, 24, 44, 44, 6…
$ dmv_only_closest_regloc_id     <int> 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1,…
$ dmv_only_dist_miles            <dbl> 3.920234, 6.234878, 3.582916, 1.474123, 2.520320, 1.8…
$ hosp_only_closest_regloc_id    <int> 16, 8, 16, 17, 10, 17, 16, 16, 10, 12, 7, 11, 10, 5, …
$ hosp_only_dist_miles           <dbl> 0.2262349, 2.1959098, 0.8642427, 1.0810720, 2.0617893…
$ dmv_and_hosp_closest_regloc_id <int> 16, 8, 16, 17, 10, 1, 16, 16, 10, 12, 4, 11, 10, 5, 1…
$ dmv_and_hosp_dist_miles        <dbl> 0.2262349, 2.1959098, 0.8642427, 1.0810720, 2.0617893…
$ geog                           <POLYGON [°]> POLYGON ((-75.14961 40.0082..., POLYGON ((-75…
```

Working data:

```
working_data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = dist_change, color = NA)
```

Any thoughts on what could be going on?

**Edit: Here is a sample of my data to use to test**

```
> dput(test_data)
structure(list(analysis_group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("DMV only", "Hospital only", 
"DMV and Hospital"), class = "factor"), census_block_id = c(17769L, 
5701L, 10343L, 13943L, 824L, 4016L, 3801L, 12914L, 7158L, 15080L, 
2291L, 5303L, 16371L, 12133L, 12211L, 13467L, 14581L, 1653L, 
10279L, 8308L, 7212L, 11968L, 14201L, 17306L, 17659L, 12431L, 
17235L, 14820L, 12904L, 14179L), race = structure(c(5L, 1L, 8L, 
3L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("v3_American_Indian_and_Alaska_Native_alone", 
"v3_Asian_alone", "v3_Black_or_African_American_alone", "v3_Native_Hawaiian_and_Other_Pacific_Islander_alone", 
"hisp_lat_white", "v4_White_alone", "v3_Some_Other_Race_alone", 
"v3_Population_of_Two_or_More_Races"), class = "factor"), dem_count = c(0L, 
0L, 4L, 13L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 36L, 3L, 89L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dem_perc = c(0, 
0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 
0, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0.2, 0.9, 0, 0, 0), dist_miles = c(0.7087559032, 
10.28985799, 5.121841087, 7.719372249, 6.484858265, 3.936395296, 
0.4214821506, 0.8466445796, 3.260201155, 4.382266929, 2.264230064, 
2.641397031, 1.06549425, 2.059872559, 5.330657466, 1.680736152, 
1.70476816, 0.5969231801, 2.425111842, 1.782450555, 0.6958109783, 
3.188800277, 1.481713599, 0.9994898577, 0.8435133297, 1.183770724, 
1.686901434, 0.3508031623, 3.448550804, 1.456636437), geog = structure(list(
    structure(list(structure(c(-75.153757, -75.153233, -75.152965, 
    -75.153384, -75.153489, -75.153518, -75.153757, 39.961684, 
    39.961658, 39.962493, 39.962512, 39.962526, 39.96248, 39.961684
    ), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
    structure(list(structure(c(-75.005356, -75.005303, -75.005211, 
    -75.002842, -74.998085, -74.998206, -74.998254, -74.998297, 
    -74.998323, -74.99834, -74.998373, -74.998452, -74.998499, 
    -74.998527, -74.99854, -74.998584, -74.998628, -74.99866, 
    -74.998708, -74.998851, -74.998919, -74.998937, -74.998923, 
    -74.998931, -74.998985, -74.999028, -74.999052, -74.999073, 
    -74.999094, -74.999095, -74.99911, -74.999133, -74.999139, 
    -74.999145, -74.999146, -74.999155, -74.99917, -74.999145, 
    -74.999128, -74.999147, -74.999167, -74.999213, -74.999239, 
    -74.999257, -74.999265, -74.999277, -74.999284, -74.999262, 
    -74.999246, -74.999271, -74.9993, -74.999343, -74.999391, 
    -74.999417, -74.999407, -74.999402, -74.999417, -74.999426, 
    -74.99943, -74.99943, -74.999427, -74.999449, -74.999501, 
    -75.005173, -75.005292, -75.00532, -75.005351, -75.005356, 
    40.096443, 40.096306, 40.096207, 40.094156, 40.097378, 40.097513, 
    40.097545, 40.097589, 40.097642, 40.097702, 40.097761, 40.097829, 
    40.097867, 40.097923, 40.097975, 40.098036, 40.098089, 40.098135, 
    40.09817, 40.098253, 40.098322, 40.098378, 40.098417, 40.098462, 
    40.098485, 40.098543, 40.098613, 40.098659, 40.098721, 40.098768, 
    40.09881, 40.098868, 40.098942, 40.098997, 40.099055, 40.099118, 
    40.099177, 40.099219, 40.099285, 40.099325, 40.099361, 40.099417, 
    40.099472, 40.099538, 40.099619, 40.099697, 40.099736, 40.099779, 
    40.099825, 40.099866, 40.099925, 40.099972, 40.099992, 40.100018, 
    40.10006, 40.100121, 40.100211, 40.100295, 40.100368, 40.100449, 
    40.100507, 40.100581, 40.100695, 40.096848, 40.096727, 40.096666, 
    40.096594, 40.096443), .Dim = c(68L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.07509, 
    -75.074772, -75.074505, -75.074206, -75.073945, -75.073654, 
    -75.073256, -75.074095, -75.075032, -75.076902, -75.07509, 
    40.053364, 40.053707, 40.053977, 40.054306, 40.054577, 40.054892, 
    40.05533, 40.055819, 40.056359, 40.054387, 40.053364), .Dim = c(11L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(-75.037313, -75.036217, -75.036672, -75.037769, 
        -75.037313, 40.028262, 40.028828, 40.029345, 40.028778, 
        40.028262), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.066853, -75.066239, 
    -75.066575, -75.067188, -75.066853, 40.012999, 40.013143, 
    40.014024, 40.01389, 40.012999), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.171034, 
    -75.170237, -75.169897, -75.170679, -75.171034, 40.002302, 
    40.002205, 40.003781, 40.003887, 40.002302), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(-75.161626, -75.160608, -75.160498, -75.160846, 
        -75.161382, -75.161525, -75.161626, 39.914979, 39.914851, 
        39.915361, 39.915404, 39.915473, 39.915485, 39.914979
        ), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
    )), structure(list(structure(c(-75.145802, -75.144996, -75.144962, 
    -75.145768, -75.145802, 39.961027, 39.960938, 39.961088, 
    39.961166, 39.961027), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.139029, 
    -75.138588, -75.138269, -75.138693, -75.139029, 39.995099, 
    39.995047, 39.996537, 39.996594, 39.995099), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(-75.25705, -75.256992, -75.256913, -75.256727, 
        -75.256581, -75.256599, -75.256673, -75.256735, -75.256775, 
        -75.256761, -75.25672, -75.256684, -75.256762, -75.256741, 
        -75.255884, -75.255546, -75.255166, -75.254867, -75.254566, 
        -75.254415, -75.254266, -75.254223, -75.253918, -75.253813, 
        -75.253661, -75.253567, -75.253522, -75.253348, -75.253289, 
        -75.253197, -75.253177, -75.253152, -75.253007, -75.252959, 
        -75.252916, -75.252787, -75.252745, -75.252662, -75.251826, 
        -75.250954, -75.250273, -75.250101, -75.249686, -75.249354, 
        -75.249081, -75.248682, -75.248271, -75.248151, -75.247965, 
        -75.247688, -75.247642, -75.247604, -75.247489, -75.247418, 
        -75.247399, -75.247405, -75.247434, -75.247479, -75.247564, 
        -75.247685, -75.247778, -75.247903, -75.248056, -75.248615, 
        -75.248967, -75.249465, -75.249728, -75.249848, -75.249912, 
        -75.24999, -75.250054, -75.250133, -75.250221, -75.250313, 
        -75.250447, -75.250606, -75.250757, -75.250913, -75.251048, 
        -75.251102, -75.251201, -75.251283, -75.251342, -75.251336, 
        -75.251341, -75.251353, -75.251368, -75.251427, -75.251496, 
        -75.251603, -75.251707, -75.251811, -75.251923, -75.252094, 
        -75.252334, -75.252636, -75.252843, -75.252972, -75.253077, 
        -75.253222, -75.253314, -75.253407, -75.253582, -75.253712, 
        -75.253936, -75.254046, -75.25414, -75.254223, -75.254302, 
        -75.254337, -75.254381, -75.254456, -75.254543, -75.254632, 
        -75.254738, -75.254937, -75.255112, -75.255267, -75.255409, 
        -75.255543, -75.255686, -75.255812, -75.255852, -75.255892, 
        -75.255966, -75.256083, -75.256193, -75.256281, -75.256383, 
        -75.256586, -75.256686, -75.256746, -75.256816, -75.2569, 
        -75.256981, -75.25711, -75.25705, 39.963474, 39.963217, 
        39.962892, 39.962105, 39.96213, 39.962192, 39.962447, 
        39.962731, 39.962913, 39.962935, 39.962966, 39.962974, 
        39.963109, 39.963195, 39.963701, 39.963904, 39.964105, 
        39.964239, 39.964341, 39.964379, 39.964413, 39.964423, 
        39.964459, 39.964463, 39.96447, 39.964467, 39.964466, 
        39.96445, 39.964442, 39.96443, 39.964378, 39.964254, 
        39.963728, 39.963553, 39.963376, 39.962846, 39.96267, 
        39.962681, 39.962797, 39.962924, 39.963039, 39.96306, 
        39.963088, 39.963088, 39.963055, 39.962995, 39.962869, 
        39.962846, 39.962827, 39.962817, 39.96295, 39.962992, 
        39.963119, 39.963191, 39.963249, 39.963327, 39.963417, 
        39.963528, 39.963638, 39.963777, 39.963876, 39.963979, 
        39.964074, 39.964352, 39.964494, 39.964721, 39.96485, 
        39.964908, 39.964947, 39.965001, 39.965042, 39.965067, 
        39.965076, 39.965069, 39.965018, 39.964948, 39.964879, 
        39.964837, 39.964833, 39.964858, 39.964912, 39.965003, 
        39.965072, 39.965138, 39.965192, 39.965219, 39.965249, 
        39.965302, 39.965337, 39.965356, 39.965346, 39.96533, 
        39.965318, 39.965305, 39.96528, 39.965251, 39.965244, 
        39.965235, 39.965214, 39.965184, 39.965226, 39.965261, 
        39.9653, 39.965329, 39.96539, 39.965402, 39.965404, 39.965337, 
        39.965273, 39.965211, 39.965127, 39.965046, 39.964992, 
        39.964925, 39.96485, 39.964763, 39.964691, 39.964655, 
        39.96463, 39.964595, 39.964546, 39.964471, 39.964437, 
        39.964372, 39.964312, 39.964242, 39.964155, 39.964079, 
        39.963974, 39.963802, 39.963719, 39.963688, 39.963677, 
        39.963672, 39.963688, 39.963719, 39.963474), .Dim = c(137L, 
        2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(-75.118611, -75.118248, -75.117545, -75.117564, 
        -75.117871, -75.11847, -75.118611, 39.978879, 39.978466, 
        39.97884, 39.978868, 39.979208, 39.978901, 39.978879), .Dim = c(7L, 
        2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(-75.100476, -75.099292, -75.0995, -75.100685, 
        -75.100476, 39.983952, 39.984571, 39.984817, 39.984196, 
        39.983952), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.118762, -75.116823, 
    -75.116722, -75.117288, -75.117738, -75.118181, -75.118685, 
    -75.118762, 39.99995, 39.999697, 40.000088, 40.000164, 40.000223, 
    40.000273, 40.000336, 39.99995), .Dim = c(8L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.177303, 
    -75.176606, -75.175885, -75.17575, -75.175714, -75.177048, 
    -75.177133, -75.177218, -75.177303, 39.995239, 39.995149, 
    39.995064, 39.995669, 39.995832, 39.996, 39.99602, 39.995649, 
    39.995239), .Dim = c(9L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.175345, -75.174294, 
    -75.173967, -75.173796, -75.172868, -75.172266, -75.171724, 
    -75.170976, -75.170902, -75.170488, -75.170101, -75.169649, 
    -75.169241, -75.168843, -75.16856, -75.168298, -75.16795, 
    -75.167612, -75.16728, -75.167073, -75.166888, -75.166817, 
    -75.166647, -75.166607, -75.163985, -75.162736, -75.156134, 
    -75.149395, -75.145874, -75.145235, -75.145137, -75.14514, 
    -75.145151, -75.144888, -75.144531, -75.144291, -75.144019, 
    -75.143964, -75.143888, -75.143801, -75.143558, -75.14341, 
    -75.143329, -75.143274, -75.143232, -75.143132, -75.143035, 
    -75.142945, -75.142843, -75.14274, -75.142639, -75.142539, 
    -75.142427, -75.142329, -75.142252, -75.14217, -75.14201, 
    -75.141843, -75.141769, -75.141629, -75.141586, -75.141538, 
    -75.141419, -75.141354, -75.141296, -75.141258, -75.141223, 
    -75.141175, -75.14111, -75.141058, -75.140977, -75.140904, 
    -75.140851, -75.140717, -75.140673, -75.14064, -75.140528, 
    -75.14044, -75.140368, -75.140307, -75.140194, -75.140166, 
    -75.140158, -75.140117, -75.140078, -75.140049, -75.140048, 
    -75.14005, -75.140086, -75.140075, -75.140037, -75.140022, 
    -75.140046, -75.140092, -75.140147, -75.140197, -75.140266, 
    -75.14035, -75.140442, -75.140545, -75.140631, -75.140718, 
    -75.140823, -75.140936, -75.141076, -75.141212, -75.141329, 
    -75.141437, -75.141576, -75.141735, -75.141923, -75.142139, 
    -75.142247, -75.142388, -75.142533, -75.142567, -75.142641, 
    -75.142712, -75.14274, -75.142741, -75.142754, -75.142786, 
    -75.142819, -75.142823, -75.142801, -75.14278, -75.142759, 
    -75.142751, -75.142644, -75.142247, -75.141533, -75.144184, 
    -75.144225, -75.14425, -75.144277, -75.145587, -75.145924, 
    -75.147111, -75.151526, -75.153669, -75.154006, -75.154342, 
    -75.15468, -75.15502, -75.155362, -75.156728, -75.157071, 
    -75.158436, -75.158778, -75.160827, -75.161169, -75.165609, 
    -75.16595, -75.166975, -75.167315, -75.167658, -75.167998, 
    -75.16834, -75.169705, -75.170046, -75.170095, -75.170389, 
    -75.170726, -75.17106, -75.17139, -75.17171, -75.172028, 
    -75.172343, -75.172657, -75.172972, -75.174063, -75.174862, 
    -75.174959, -75.175022, -75.175203, -75.175345, 39.897472, 
    39.897328, 39.897287, 39.897262, 39.897137, 39.897067, 39.896966, 
    39.896774, 39.896752, 39.896631, 39.896462, 39.89626, 39.896037, 
    39.895781, 39.895574, 39.895367, 39.895062, 39.894686, 39.894272, 
    39.893935, 39.893586, 39.89333, 39.892551, 39.892209, 39.892335, 
    39.891235, 39.891723, 39.892218, 39.892506, 39.892552, 39.891786, 
    39.891686, 39.891619, 39.889009, 39.889055, 39.889104, 39.889175, 
    39.889188, 39.889209, 39.889231, 39.889278, 39.889328, 39.889346, 
    39.889364, 39.88939, 39.889423, 39.889452, 39.889484, 39.889516, 
    39.889545, 39.889576, 39.88962, 39.889686, 39.889764, 39.889835, 
    39.889918, 39.890093, 39.890327, 39.890451, 39.890708, 39.890785, 
    39.890854, 39.89103, 39.891086, 39.891134, 39.89119, 39.891237, 
    39.891293, 39.891354, 39.891422, 39.891502, 39.891583, 39.89166, 
    39.891826, 39.891883, 39.891929, 39.892092, 39.892224, 39.892349, 
    39.892446, 39.892589, 39.892634, 39.892675, 39.892749, 39.892813, 
    39.892891, 39.89297, 39.893033, 39.89321, 39.893275, 39.893333, 
    39.893387, 39.893423, 39.893436, 39.893433, 39.893439, 39.893461, 
    39.893497, 39.893541, 39.893582, 39.893607, 39.893619, 39.893642, 
    39.89366, 39.893688, 39.89371, 39.893726, 39.893731, 39.89373, 
    39.893727, 39.893717, 39.893709, 39.893706, 39.893724, 39.893717, 
    39.893723, 39.893741, 39.893787, 39.893852, 39.893936, 39.894025, 
    39.894113, 39.894219, 39.89434, 39.894446, 39.894495, 39.894519, 
    39.894547, 39.895081, 39.895149, 39.895062, 39.895633, 39.895648, 
    39.895662, 39.895682, 39.895857, 39.895901, 39.89606, 39.896647, 
    39.896932, 39.896976, 39.897024, 39.897064, 39.897076, 39.897082, 
    39.897122, 39.897131, 39.897171, 39.89718, 39.897239, 39.897248, 
    39.897377, 39.897388, 39.897418, 39.897429, 39.897439, 39.89745, 
    39.89746, 39.897504, 39.897521, 39.89752, 39.897542, 39.897583, 
    39.897639, 39.897711, 39.897799, 39.897896, 39.897998, 39.898102, 
    39.898205, 39.89836, 39.898474, 39.898488, 39.898312, 39.897809, 
    39.897472), .Dim = c(176L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.171997, -75.171453, 
    -75.171112, -75.171442, -75.171691, -75.171997, 39.997826, 
    39.997752, 39.999242, 39.99929, 39.999321, 39.997826), .Dim = c(6L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(-75.121438, -75.121043, -75.120842, -75.120186, 
        -75.119747, -75.120203, -75.120809, -75.121046, -75.121347, 
        -75.121438, 39.987859, 39.987567, 39.987678, 39.988022, 
        39.988251, 39.988761, 39.988431, 39.988226, 39.987945, 
        39.987859), .Dim = c(10L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.175652, -75.175085, 
    -75.174937, -75.175537, -75.175568, -75.175617, -75.175652, 
    39.958546, 39.958481, 39.959113, 39.959192, 39.958971, 39.958729, 
    39.958546), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.220548, -75.219485, 
    -75.219434, -75.218843, -75.21973, -75.220588, -75.220548, 
    39.929, 39.928116, 39.928082, 39.928903, 39.929647, 39.929047, 
    39.929), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
    )), structure(list(structure(c(-75.017837, -75.017781, -75.017623, 
    -75.017498, -75.017334, -75.017075, -75.016815, -75.016526, 
    -75.016184, -75.015875, -75.015392, -75.01493, -75.013629, 
    -75.012747, -75.012932, -75.015485, -75.015661, -75.015771, 
    -75.016322, -75.016769, -75.017135, -75.017571, -75.017727, 
    -75.017813, -75.017845, -75.017837, 40.061101, 40.060973, 
    40.060816, 40.060741, 40.060871, 40.061051, 40.061211, 40.06136, 
    40.061514, 40.061623, 40.061758, 40.061848, 40.062047, 40.062185, 
    40.062866, 40.062466, 40.062422, 40.062395, 40.062227, 40.062051, 
    40.061879, 40.061633, 40.061515, 40.061379, 40.06124, 40.061101
    ), .Dim = c(26L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
    structure(list(structure(c(-75.158352, -75.157127, -75.156982, 
    -75.156943, -75.156896, -75.15684, -75.156737, -75.157587, 
    -75.158311, -75.15841, -75.158352, 39.958639, 39.958483, 
    39.958464, 39.95846, 39.958453, 39.958452, 39.95891, 39.959019, 
    39.959112, 39.95865, 39.958639), .Dim = c(11L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.248333, 
    -75.248093, -75.247306, -75.247206, -75.247213, -75.247494, 
    -75.247797, -75.24823, -75.248333, 39.975017, 39.973722, 
    39.973608, 39.973563, 39.973596, 39.975113, 39.975079, 39.97503, 
    39.975017), .Dim = c(9L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.220153, -75.220048, 
    -75.219574, -75.219293, -75.219212, -75.219202, -75.219123, 
    -75.220081, -75.220153, 39.953532, 39.953497, 39.953439, 
    39.953399, 39.953366, 39.953414, 39.953732, 39.953849, 39.953532
    ), .Dim = c(9L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
    structure(list(structure(c(-75.180099, -75.179083, -75.178994, 
    -75.180021, -75.180099, 39.948509, 39.94839, 39.94875, 39.948872, 
    39.948509), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.213962, -75.213327, 
    -75.213262, -75.212895, -75.212948, -75.213066, -75.213162, 
    -75.213509, -75.213449, -75.213571, -75.213598, -75.213962, 
    40.020998, 40.020116, 40.020146, 40.020315, 40.020394, 40.02034, 
    40.020464, 40.020921, 40.020949, 40.021112, 40.021156, 40.020998
    ), .Dim = c(12L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
    structure(list(structure(c(-75.240955, -75.240362, -75.239583, 
    -75.239122, -75.238843, -75.238864, -75.239238, -75.239548, 
    -75.239665, -75.239945, -75.241166, -75.240955, 39.924857, 
    39.924363, 39.924903, 39.925225, 39.925429, 39.925493, 39.925825, 
    39.925896, 39.925835, 39.925686, 39.92504, 39.924857), .Dim = c(12L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(-75.180314, -75.179761, -75.179724, -75.17949, 
        -75.180045, -75.180283, -75.180314, 39.92062, 39.920549, 
        39.920711, 39.92179, 39.921872, 39.92078, 39.92062), .Dim = c(7L, 
        2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(-75.150719, -75.148872, -75.148766, -75.150611, 
        -75.150719, 40.066367, 40.066131, 40.066619, 40.066858, 
        40.066367), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-75.236191, -75.236143, 
    -75.236029, -75.234329, -75.236178, -75.236191, 39.991419, 
    39.99102, 39.991094, 39.991891, 39.991943, 39.991419), .Dim = c(6L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(-75.215684, -75.215628, -75.214676, -75.214732, 
        -75.214776, -75.215121, -75.215106, -75.215422, -75.215434, 
        -75.215726, -75.215684, 39.968504, 39.968061, 39.968133, 
        39.968588, 39.968939, 39.9689, 39.968815, 39.96878, 39.968847, 
        39.968823, 39.968504), .Dim = c(11L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -75.25711, 
ymin = 39.889009, xmax = -74.998085, ymax = 40.100695), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), class = c("sf", 
"grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), groups = structure(list(analysis_group = structure(1:3, .Label = c("DMV only", 
"Hospital only", "DMV and Hospital"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:10, 11:20, 21:30), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE), sf_column = "geog", agr = structure(c(analysis_group = NA_integer_, 
census_block_id = NA_integer_, race = NA_integer_, dem_count = NA_integer_, 
dem_perc = NA_integer_, dist_miles = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Quinten - The dataset is huge, so I added a sample here, but I tested it and the sample throws the same error.